# Batch requests to fetch metrics from Azure mgmt monitor

Tags: python, azure-monitoring, azure-sdk-python

I have a set of VMs from which I need to fetch metrics everyday. I am using the Azure mgmt monitoring library. The library allows to fetch one VM at a time.

I am looking to fetch it for around 5000 machines and the time taken is very high for that(around 6 seconds per VM).

Is there a way for me to batch the request?

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9271